# Command 'yapf' not found, but can be installed

Tags: apt, software-installation, python

I am trying to install [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf) for python formatting on Ubuntu 18.04.

I ran the command

```
pip install yapf
```

and got the message

```
Successfully installed yapf-0.23.0
```

But then when I try to run `yapf`:

```
yapf path/to/file.py
```

It gives me the message

```
Command 'yapf' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install yapf
```

So does Ubuntu have its own version of `yapf` that can be installed? I don't know why it can't recognize the `yapf` command already.

I should mention I have an alias in my `.bashrc` so that pip3 is used.

```
alias pip='pip3'
```

Comment: Since it seems you're using python3, have you tried `yapf3` as a command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer official ubuntu packages to pip installed ones.

A search on [ubuntu package repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=yapf) shows many candidates.

For 18.04 looks like there are different packages for `python2` and `python3`.
Since it seems you're using `python3`, try with

```
sudo apt install yapf3 python3-yapf
```